# How to wrap facet label texts

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm new to R and I'm trying to create the graph below, but don't know how to wrap the facet names. Each facet represents a different seminar and the seminar names are long. What's the cleanest way I can accomplish this within my existing approach?

```
 webinar_rating_graph <- response_master_df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=`How would you rate the content of the webinar?`)) +
  facet_grid(cols=vars(Webinar)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..)), 
           fill="skyblue", color="black") +
  labs(title="Ratings of Webinars as Percentage of Respondants", y="Percentage of Respondants") +
  theme(
    plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, size=12), 
    strip.text=element_text(hjust=.5, size=8), 
    axis.text=element_text(hjust=.5, size=4), 
    axis.title=element_text(size=8)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent) + 
  scale_x_discrete(
    labels=scales::wrap_format(4),
    limits = c("Very Helpful", "Somewhat Helpful", 
               "Neither Helpful nor Unhelpful", 
               "Somewhat Unhelpful", "Very Unhelpful"))

webinar_rating_graph
```

This is the graph generated. As you can see, the facet names can't be read unless they're wrapped.

[image]

Comment: Change to `facet_grid(cols=vars(str_wrap(Webinar, 20)))` or whatever value works best.

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! That worked!